# Django admin not responding on host site

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, python-3.7, django-migrations

I am working on Django admin creation using "python manage.py createsuperuser" in the shell.I created username,email and password and then ran the server using "python manage.py runserver" in the terminal of PyCharm. What I got is:

```
(venv) H:\django project\mysite1>python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'maitreya'): mtr007
Email address: maitreya@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
```

AND AFTER THIS I RAN THE SERVER

```
(venv) H:\django project\mysite1>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 26, 2020 - 11:32:06
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'mysite1.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[26/Apr/2020 11:32:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2028
[26/Apr/2020 11:32:13] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[26/Apr/2020 11:32:13] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
[26/Apr/2020 11:32:27] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Now What happens is that the web page has created a Django administration login and accepting my username and password but suddenly the site stops working.
I am posting a screenshot of the site.
[image]

Can someone address and solve what should I do(should install some module or verify the path etc.) or look for new versions of some django documentations.

Comment: Do you not get any more log output? Does the error happen instantly or after a while?

Comment: No I don't get more log outputs.The error happens instantly and now I tried to recreate the admin credentials and deleted the previous ones But the problem is not solved.@Iain Shelvington

Comment: There may be an issue with one of your models or admin classes, can you try unregistering all of your models to see if it fixes it?

Comment: Well I checked the models there seems to be a type mis-match between timedelta and DatetimeField in :    def was_published_recently(self):
                         return self.pub_date >= timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)                              Can You suggest how to fix this.I tried timedelta on the right side but still does not work out.